# How to fill progress at one or more specified positions on a circle in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-component

How can i assign one or more progress on circle progress as shown below
I'm using the library react-native-circular-progress

Current:
[image]

Expect:
[image]

Thanks all !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install `react-native-circular-gradient-progress` to implement this.

If you are using npm then please write

> npm install react-native-circular-gradient-progress

If you are using yarn then please write

> yarn add react-native-circular-gradient-progress

**You can use it like below:**

```
import React from "react";
import { CircularProgress } from "react-native-circular-gradient-progress";
 
const HomePage: React.FunctionComponent = () => (
  <CircularProgress
    color="#F00"
    size={size}
    progress={progress}
  />
)
 
export default HomePage;
```

And u will get result like this:

[image]

For further explanation of props you can read [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-circular-gradient-progress).

Comment: Thanks, but it can't solve the problem i want

Comment: Can u please explain what exactly u want?

Comment: I want progress as dashed style and be able to prefill two or more progress on a circle

Comment: Same as picture above